# How to avoid "Avoid E173 (n more file(s) to edit)?"

Tags: syntax-highlighting, multiple-files

So, when I open multiple files, but don't visit the all of them (or the last one), and I try to :quit neovim yells at me that I have to edit those files. No I don't! Stop giving me this error : )

It seems totally strange that it gives me an error for unVISITED files. The fix I've used until now was this:

```
" Avoid E173 (n more file(s) to edit)
if argc() > 1
 silent blast " load last buffer
 silent bfirst " switch back to the first
endif
```

But that leads to the following... Any ideas for how to overcome both of these issues?

When opening multiple files, I don't see syntax highlighting for the first file, whereas when I open one file at a time I do.

One file:

[image: Screenshot from 2020-05-08 13-59-50]

[image: Screenshot from 2020-05-08 13-59-26]

Two files:

[image: Screenshot from 2020-05-08 13-59-43]

[image: Screenshot from 2020-05-08 13-58-55]

Side note: I alias vi to nvim.

Comment: Well, if you remove that block, does it start working again? Also check output of `:set ft?` to see if it's empty on the first file. You could try to move that block above `filetype plugin indent on` in your vimrc to see if that helps. But overall, switching buffers in your vimrc tends to create undesirable side effects such as the one you reported. It might also break `vim -o` or `vim -p`, etc.

Comment: Yeup, removing it fixed the syntax issue, but now I'm stuck with the old problems of getting a warning for unVISITED buffers. It's not like I have unsaved changes. I just didn't visit one of the buffers. How do I solve that? Editing Question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you have your code before `filetype on` (including `runtime defaults.vim` or anything else switching `filetype on`). But it must be placed after it.

Also, my personal advice is to `set confirm` and get rid of this stuff completely. Or use `ZQ`, or `:q!` and such.

UPD. As it turned out, the problem was due to using autocommands with `mkview` and `loadview`.

Comment: confirm is nice, but it still interrupts me for something that doesn't need interruption (unvisite buffers). On the filetype on, I've put it before after, before and after, nothing seems to change the behavior.

Comment: @Costa Try to replicate the problem with minimal vimrc. No one knows how much stuff you have there.

Comment: Hahaa! Okay, I'll try : ) ... dam it! you're right. Here's my vimrc, lol: https://gist.github.com/wamoyo/34405c4672c89dbfded62ea34134003b

Comment: @Costa Just `filetype plugin indent on` is enough. And it should really be on top of vimrc.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. No matter what I do, if I include the autocommand for args, it drops syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Costa Your problem is due to bloody `mkview / loadview`. Delete this bs and forget it for good.

Comment: Sweet! That did it. Now, I probably broke the way I was using folding, but I haven't used that so happy to let that go for a while. Thanks, Matt!!!

Comment: Alternatively, set [`'viewoptions'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27viewoptions%27) appropriately so it doesn't affect options (such as `'filetype'`) but they still remember folds. For example: `set viewoptions-=options` or more drastically `set viewoptions=folds`.

Comment: I don't think `set confirm` prevents E173

Comment: @filbranden It sucks anyway. For example, I never could figure out how to `loadview N` with splits. It's just simplier `zM` / `zR  / za` etc.

Comment: @Mass It triggers "yes/no" dialog instead of throwing an error.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**: Use `:qa`, `:q!`, or `ZQ` to quit.  Then vim does not prompt for multiple files.  On the other hand, it will also not alert for changes made to the current buffer.

**Option 2**: Always open multiple buffers in spits, or in tab pages.  Change your bash alias to

```
alias vim='nvim -o'
```

or (for tab pages)

```
alias vim='nvim -p'
```

This doesn't solve the problem of using `:q` twice, but it makes it more visible.

**Option 3**: Use a combination of `+only` and `-o`:

```
alias vim='nvim +only -o'
```

The idea here is to open all files in windows, but then only keep one of them.

**Option 4**: Overwrite arguments on startup.

```
vim +args\ % file1 file2
```

or in vimrc,

```
au VimEnter * args %
```

vim uses the argument list, or the files you mention in command to determine whether to remind you there are still files to edit.  If we manually change that, it will stop alerting you.  Of course, you cannot use `:n` and `:prev` then.

Comment: Won't option 3 break using `:n` to go to `file2` though?

Comment: Hm... but will it not alert for changes made?

Comment: @filbranden good point.  Added another option which may be better in OPs case.

Comment: This is great thinking, thank you. I tried them, and I lose syntax highlighting again : (

Comment: @Costa that is odd.  I feel like something else is wrong then.

Comment: Anything you think I should check?

Comment: `On the other hand, it will also not alert for changes made.` This isn’t really true. `:q!` won’t alert you for changes in your *current* buffer, but it will still alert you to changes in other buffers, and `:qall` will alert you to changes in any of your buffers.