# Disable E173: X more files to edit warning in neovim

Tags: neovim, error, multiple-files, argument-list

How can I make `:q` and other standard ways of exiting quit immediately even if E173 would ordinarily have stopped me in my tracks?

Because this [doesn't seem possible in regular VIM](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/how-to-avoid-avoid-e173-n-more-files-to-edit), how can I do it in neovim?

Comment: well, just use  `:qa`

Comment: Hi @theonlygusti I try to clise the questions :-) Do you still have a question or is it an answer that you can accept? If not, what remains open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
:qa
```

You can also run:

```
silent bufdo normal! \<nop>
```

It visits all the buffer and do nothing.
After that action you can quit Vim with `:q`

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll autocmd your useful bufdo

Answer (score 1):

With `:set confirm`, `vim {a..c}` then `:quit` gives me a prompt to quit (or not).

Without `:set confirm`, the first `:quit` errors but the second (immediately afterwards) always succeeds.

Comment: @Ben, I have tested with a minimal configuration of gVim and it works as you described. I have deleted my comments since they are irrelevant.